# how to use gdb in emacs - Undefined command

Tags: emacs, gdb, undefined

Nowadays I'm using Emacs 25 and it complains like this.

[image]

I couldn't find anything to solve this situation on the web.
Could you give me some advices, please?

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the second line. When you use `gdb` you are asked to enter the file name. You have to be sure to open the file like this `gdb -i=mi /path/to/file`.

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: I found why it behaves so. It was due to my .gdbinit at my home directory. After removing it, it works as you told me. Thanks anyway.